# Localized date strftime in Django view

Tags: python, django, localization

I would like to send localized date in JSON from django view

Normal text translation via

> ugettext

is OK

Following code in view has no effect:

```
translation.activate("ru")
print datetime.now().strtime("%B")
```

Output is **"August"**, instead of "**Август**"

I read about python's "locale" module, but it's named as thread unsafe

How to force strftime to use django's locale?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Finally i used date filter from django templates:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import date as _date
from datetime import datetime

_date(datetime.now(), "d b, D")
```

Comment: +100 This is not only much safer to use than setlocale(…), its also a lot easier!

Comment: Nice, this still works in the latest version (https://github.com/django/django/blob/9e38ed0536c7dc598a6c2c1bb774d0a8db3cdddc/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L696)

Comment: The format can be checked here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: Using Python locale was causing hell for me on different servers, which did not have the all the locales installed. This is a much more portable solution. Thank you!