# Localize date times inside a Django templatetag

Tags: python, django

I am working on a templatetag in Django which should take care of some date- and time formatting.

I would like the date to be show in Dutch, but it keeps coming back in English.

from django import template

register = template.Library()

```
@register.filter()
def get_date_string(event):
    if event.date_type == 1:
        retval = event.date_1.strftime("%-d %B %Y")
        if event.date_1_starttime is not None:
            retval += " van " + event.date_1_starttime.strftime("%H:%M")
        if event.date_1_endtime is not None:
            retval += " tot " + event.date_1_endtime.strftime("%H:%M")

        return retval
```

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) `%B` should provide a localized month full name.

In the template I just use:

```
{{ object|get_date_string }}
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Can you attach your `settings.py` file? I think that its keep returning in english due to LANGUAGE setting

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945251/localized-date-strftime-in-django-view) I was able to get things working.

This is my final solution:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import date as _date

register = template.Library()


@register.filter()
def get_date_string(event):
    if event.date_type == 1:
        retval = _date(event.date_1)
        if event.date_1_starttime is not None:
            retval += " vanaf " + event.date_1_starttime.strftime("%H:%M")
        if event.date_1_endtime is not None:
            retval += " tot " + event.date_1_endtime.strftime("%H:%M")

        return retval
```

All I did was use the Django date filter to do the date formatting for me.