# Python Django: make strftime return german language, not english

Tags: python, django, strftime

In my Django project, I'm using strftime, specifically `%b` to get the abbreviated month name. Those names are returned in english. My settings contain the following:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de' # also tried 'de_DE'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Why does strftime still return english language?

Comment: You could use [arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#humanize) module. It accepts locale as a parameter and its easier to use for dates or [babel](https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/dates.html#date-and-time-formatting) which also transform dates to different languages

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you could try:

1. According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/#term-language-code) you should be supplying `de-de` to `LANGUAGE_CODE`.
2. You might also want to try setting `LOCALE_NAME = 'de_DE'`
3. If all else fails, you could always try to brute force it via `import locale` and `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE')` (or `de_DE.utf8'`)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm not sure if 3) has any side effects? Because Django expects you to use the settings.py to set the locale. Probably it's okay do to it that way, however I have taken a different route and posted it down below for others.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer. It is a mix of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10801903/13154227) (background understanding) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6991918/13154227) (solution). Apparently strftime does not access whatever you have specified in your Django settings. It will just use the locale of the machine. So instead you can use `django.template.defaultfilters`. Import it in your views under whatever name you like (e.g. `import django.template.defaultfilters as myvarname`) and then use it to format your date objects: `myvarname(yourdateobject, 'b')`.